# My Bike Like To Try and Turn Left

Tags: wheels, handlebars

So when I ride my bike it likes to give a little traction at times like the front wheel wants to turn left. The rim looks straight to me and i double checked it. Is this a problem with the wheel or the tire? Should I buy a new set of Tires for my bike?

Comment: Are your handlebars straight? Is your fork bent?

Comment: Also how old is the bike? Headsets can become "indexed" where the ball bearings wear grooves into the race, it could be that the ball bearings are wanting to settle into those grooves. Also check the tire for uneven wear or where tire may not be fully seated. Does it feel like it pulls to the left or just turns easier that direction?

Comment: It's common on poor quality bikes (bad fork geometry), or when fork is bent.

Comment: A couple of photos of the fork area may be helpful.  Please add some if you can.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your fork is bent.

Ride straight through a puddle and then leave tracks on dry concrete.  Your back tyre track should be superimposed on top of your front track.  If they follow different lines, your fork/frame is bent.

Use your hand throught the front rim, and by feel hold that in line with the downtube of the frame.  Then look down from above - the front wheel should be straight out the front.  If its not straight, the fork/frame is bent.

Look for corrosion and paint cracks/flakes on the top tube about 1" back from the frontmost weld.  If there's a clear ring of damage here, the fork is bent.

Can you ride hands free normally, but not on this bike?  Fork is bent.

Is a hard front-wheel brake really terrible?   Feels like you're going to be pushed sideways by wind whenever you do a hard front-brake?   Fork is bent.

Take the fork off completely. and look down the side of the steerer tube.   The two tines must curve forward from the crown.... they must NOT go backwards and then sweep forwards... if they do then the fork is bent.

Recovery - Steel forks can generally be tweaked to be better by careful slow bending with a vice and a pipe.  If its an alloy or carbon fork its probably beyond saving, but there are carbon specialists who may be able to advise.

Answer (score 0):

Tires is probably the last thing to consider. Out of balance tires would wobble at speed but not strongly try and turn. Even a bent rim would be more wobble than turn.

Look for something bent or not seated correctly.  A front wheel not seated on the fork evenly would do this.  A rear wheel not seated evenly would do this to a lesser extent.  A fork headset not seated evenly or loose would do this.  For sure a bent fork would do this. A weighted pannier on one side but not the other would do this.